# NextJS custom component hydration

Tags: reactjs, next.js, hydration, render-to-string

I have page with "getServerSideProps" functionality which makes API call and as a result receive page props. Props have different fields and one of them contains raw html string (example below):

```
<div>
   <h2>Some content</h2>
   <macro alias="alias" params="JSON" />
</div>
```

macro tag should be replaced with React Component which is done by using **ReactDOMServer.renderToString(template)**

Than using Cheerio library content is replaced in raw html string and all props are passed to Page Component which is rendered. Raw HTML string is rendered using  **dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: summary }}**

Some macros may contain client side logic and because of this I need make hydration on client side what can be done by using **hydrateRoot** where I passing Component with params and ref to the DOM element.

Problem is that **hydrateRoot** throws this error:

[image]

And also for some reason wrapper div is duplicated:

[image]

If I don't use hydrateRoot than there is no duplications but client side logic is not working.

[image]

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong or maybe someone can give me advice how can I implement previous described logic?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I just need to wrap content with another div and use this div as a root for hydration in this case hydration process went without errors.